# Connecting Jet airways flight Mumbai to Jaipur, after flying in from Frankfurt. What would be the luggage allowance?

Tags: luggage, lufthansa, check-in, jet-airways

I am flying by Luthansa from Frankfurt to Jaipur, where Frankfurt to Mumbai is Luthansa flight with 23 kg checkin allowance and from Mumbai to Jaipur, I have a connecting Jet Airways flight, which is a domestic flight. Will I be able to carry the 23 kg checkin luggage in domestic flight also without any additional cost?

Comment: Single ticket yes, multiple tickets no. But generally asking the check in person to allow you as you used an international flight from Jet would help you go thorough. But that isn't for sure. I once tried it and went through.

Comment: The whole trip is booked from Lufthansa so I think it will be on a single ticket. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to pick up your luggage and re-check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting back to my own question.
I was successfully able to take the 23kg luggage on the domestic flight as well. I had to collect my baggage at mumbai for custom related checks and again had to checkin at Jet Airways counter, but there was no problems at all and without any additional costs.